# how to save updated data into sql server from model derivative api of autodesk forge

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, python-requests, flask-sqlalchemy, autodesk-bim360

I want to save all data which will get from model-derivative API. The problem is every time I export data from model-derivative-API, I will get updated data from the database.  I want to predict changes in data where later that will get connect to powerBi to see the changes in the model

Answer (score 0):

You used the tag **autodesk-bim360**, so I assume your files are stored in **BIM 360 Docs**.
In that case you could get the properties for each file version and then compare them yourself to find out what changed between the versions.

Comment: thank you for the info. but I don't want to do it manually.  I have used flask application and  sqlalchemy

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant getting the properties for each version using the API and comparing them programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679860/one-or-more-mappers-failed-to-initialize-could-not-locate-any-relevant-foreign   Asked the same question